# unable to add multiple rows to footable ,is it possible to add mutliple rows to footable at time

Tags: rows, footable

I am trying to add mutliple rows to footable using following by using `footable.AppendRow( )` method, but it is adding only first one, and terminating loop

```
      $('.add-row').click(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();

             //get the footable object
             var footable = $('#tb').data('footable');
             var rows = JSON.parse('<%=GetCustomersPageWise() %>');//returns 20 rows

             for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
             {
                 alert(i)
                 alert(rows[i])
                 footable.appendRow(rows[i])// after this statement it is terminating
                 alert(news)

             }
```

Is it possible to add multiple rows to footable, is there any restriction that `footable.appendRow( )` only adds one row at a time. Everything is fine only I need to bind multiple rows to footable at time.

Comment: What does your browser's console say? Does it show any errors?

Comment: It is not showing any errors, except it is terminating after appending one row.